# Where to host a Flash application with high traffic (4TB)?

Tags: hosting, traffic, flash

We are looking for a decent hosting provider for our Flash widget (several SWF files)
The widget is quite popular.
The download traffic is 4TB per month and it is growing.

CPU/Memory just do not matter.

Can you recommend a decent hosting for our case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just hosting files I would use Amazon S3 (http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and Amazon Cloudfront (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). Its ridiculously easy to use and you only pay for what you consume.

Comment: As far as I see Amazon S3 is very expensive as well as Amazon Cloudfront. It costs $100/1TB/Month At the moment we pay $100/month/4TB at Superb Hosting

Comment: Why not stick with them, then? If they're decent and cheap, awesome. If you want to move because they're not decent, maybe that's why the decent hosts are more expensive.